# AsyncTask do not work in for loop

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing, android-asynctask

My AsyncTask class do not work inside for loop. Below is my code please review it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String id = careplan_disease_Parser.DiseaseID.get(i);
    String method = "GetCarePlan_Comment?CurrentValue=0&OptionId=" + id + "&DiseaseID=" + id + "&OrgId=" + orgId + "";
    String link = "GetCarePlan_Comment_dislink";

    task = new AsyncTask123();
    task.execute(link, method);
    method=null;
    link=null;
    task=null;
}
```

**Task executes only once. so i can't get value from web service second time in a loop.**
Please help me how to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: try with moving `for loop` inside `doInBackround()` in `AsyncTask123()`

Comment: When i put for loop in Do in background. it gives me error  java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: And make sure please dont call `AsyncTask123()` inside `doInBackround()` only call Http request from there

Comment: Yes i didn't call asyncTask123() again. but same error occurs,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a start-method, that gets called in the onPostExecute-part of you AsyncTask. It should look like this:

```
private void start(int number)
{
    if(number == size)
    {
        //exit
    }
    else
    {
        new AsyncTask123().execute(link, method);
    }
}


private class AsyncTask123 extends AsyncTask<> {
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        start(i++);
    }
}
```

This should work, you just have to fit it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

if you want AsyncTask in for loop then you should call your class like:

```
   new AsyncTask123().execute(link, method);
```

Not like  :

```
         task = new AsyncTask123();
         task.execute(link, method);
```